# Как на Delphi 10.3 по Таймеру свернуть Form1 в System Tray

Tags: delphi

Как в Delphi 10.3 свернуть (Минимизировать) главную форму Form1 в System Tray (Системный трей) используя Timer1 и компонент TrayIcon1.
Или есть другие варианты? 
Покажите на примере и если возможно подробнее.

Comment: Вы сами пробовали? Что у вас не получается? Покажите на примере, что не получается, мы поможем

Comment: Вот так: https://stackoverflow.com/a/11821810

Answer (score 0):

Разобрался сам:

```
// Обработчик события для Timer1
// В Events Timer1 ставим для:
// Timer1 Enabled = True
// Interval = 3000 ms
procedure TForm1.Timer1Timer(Sender: TObject);
begin
  ShowWindow(Handle,SW_HIDE);  // Скрываем программу
  ShowWindow(Application.Handle,SW_HIDE);  // Скрываем кнопку с TaskBar'а
  SetWindowLong(Application.Handle, GWL_EXSTYLE,
  GetWindowLong(Application.Handle, GWL_EXSTYLE) or (not WS_EX_APPWINDOW));
  TrayIcon1.Visible := True;
  Application.MainForm.Hide;
  Trayicon1.ShowBalloonHint; // показываем наше уведомление
  Trayicon1.balloontitle:=('My Program');
  Trayicon1.balloonhint:=('Version');
  Timer1.Enabled  := False ; //Останавливаем работу Таймера
end;

procedure TForm1.TrayIcon1Click(Sender: TObject);
begin
  TrayIcon1.Visible := False;
  Application.MainForm.Show;
end;
```